# Switch Views (with Animation) why does my screen become white when I use removeFromSuperView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c

I've just started objective C and I'm enhancing a current iPhone app. Previous codes were done by someone else. I'm trying to switch views back - and add a page curl animation in, but when I try to go back (removefromsuperview) my screen just goes white. I understand that I'm referring to the wrong view but I have no idea how to refer it to the right one.

-(IBAction)switchBack{

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView: self.view.superview cache:YES];

//[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[self.view removeFromSuperview];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

}

The commented out popToRootViewController allows me to go back to the previous page. Any help would be really appreciated. I'm going crazy with all this views >< Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.navigationController.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                animations:^{
                    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

that happened because you're trying to remove the view from its superview, which is not the way it is added before, don't use removeFromSuperView if you didn't use addSubview when showing the view it self.

you should add this code to the parent which calls your current view

> viewNotLoggedHome.modalTransitionStyle =
>   UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

this way you've stated a "partial curl" transition animation for the view u're pushing

and just delete all your animation block on switchBack function so it only consist of

```
-(IBAction)switchBack 
{ 
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: no problem, by the way u should try to read the library at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html? , that would help a lot :D

Answer (score -1):

Instead of usign self.view which is a reference to your superview, you need to use the name of the view you want to use.
f.e. :
 - If you have view1 and view2
 - you can delete view1 by using

```
[view1 removeFromSuperview];
```